# How do I collect data from a website that uses AJAX, with Perl?

Tags: ajax, perl, data-mining

This might seem a bit backwards, but I want to use Perl (and Curl if possible) to get data from a site that is using Ajax to fill an HTML shell with information. How do I make these Javascript calls to get the data I need?

The website is here: http://www.jigsaw.com/showContactUpdateTab.xhtml?companyId=224230

Comment: From the site's ToS: Acts against the Website/Services.  You shall not attempt to or engage in potentially harmful acts that are directed against the Website or Services including, without limitation, the following: ... Using manual or automated software, devices, scripts robots, other means or processes to access, “scrape,” “crawl” or “spider” any pages contained in the Website...

Comment: @Ashley, thank you for making me aware of their ToS, and I will inform my boss. He/his lawyers will come to an appropriate decision based on this. But as always, this post is strictly for educational purposes.

Comment: @Ashley I have informed the website Terms of Service police, they are coming to arrest the poster.  Sho: remain where you are and take your hands off the keyboard. 

Comment: @mikemaccana… peer pressure and good behavior is what allows us to keep real cops out of it. There may come a day when the ridiculous freedom we have enjoyed since the jump of the WWW is nothing but a memory. So, very funny but be cool about it; it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that AJAX calls are ordinary HTTP requests, so you always should be able to perform them.

Open Firebug or Web Inspector on the website you're talking about, you'll see some XHR calls:

> XHR finished loading: "http://www.jigsaw.com/dwr/interface/UserActionAPI.js".
>    "http://www.jigsaw.com/dwr/call/plaincall/UserActionAPI.getMostPurchasedContacts.dwr".
>    "http://www.jigsaw.com/dwr/call/plaincall/UserActionAPI.getRecentlyGraveyardedContacts.dwr
>   "http://www.jigsaw.com/dwr/call/plaincall/UserActionAPI.getRecentlyAddedContacts.dwr".
>   "http://www.jigsaw.com/dwr/call/plaincall/UserActionAPI.getRecentlyTitleChangedContacts.dwr"

Yay! Now you know where to get that data. Their scripts use `POST` HTTP request to the URLs above, so if you open them in your browser, you'll see various engine errors.

When you sniff (via Web Inspector debugger, for example) their AJAX POST requests, you'll see the next body:

> "callCount=1
>   page=/showContactUpdateTab.xhtml?companyId=224230
>   httpSessionId=F5E7EC4A45DFCE87B969A9F4FA06C361
>   scriptSessionId=D020EFF4333283B907402687182D03E034
>   c0-scriptName=UserActionAPI
>   c0-methodName=getRecentlyGraveyardedContacts
>   c0-id=0
>   c0-param0=number:224230
>   c0-param1=boolean:false
>   c0-param2=boolean:false
>   batchId=1
>   "

I'm pretty sure, they're generating a bunch of security session IDs to avoid data miners. You may need to dive into their JavaScript codes to learn more about those generators.

Comment: Sweet! Found the parameters in Firebug and plugged those into a POST call in cURL. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know... I completely removed the scriptSessionID and httpSessionID and was still able to get all of the data. Is it possible that they don't even track those IDs?

Comment: There is a possibility that they use those values to internally (in JavaScript) compare sent IDs with received ones, i.e. tracking appropriate responses for stored requests.

Answer (score 2):

Some applications have code in place to check that the client is a real AJAX client. They simply the check for the presence of the header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. So it's easy to circumvent:

```
curl -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' ...

use HTTP::Request::Common;
GET $url, 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest', ...
```

Of course, you might have to deal with the usual stuff, like required cookies (for the session), nonce parameters, the occasional complexity. Firebug or the like for other browsers will help you reverse-engineer the required headers and parameters.